# Windows Azure SDK for PHP requires allow_url_fopen

Tags: php, azure

The MSDN forums have not been very helpful so I am reposting my question here.. I am trying to use the new Windows Azure SDK for PHP to download a blob using

```
$blobRestProxy = 
  ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
$blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob($container, $blobname);fpassthru($blob->getContentStream());
```

The problem is that in the WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Utilities.php file stringToStream() is returning a warning which causes the download to fail when allow_url_fopen is Off:

> PHP Warning: fopen(): data:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

My question is whether this is an isolated problem or does the new SDK require allow_url_fopen to be On in order to use the getBlob function? Is there an alternative where I can avoid having to turn on allow_url_fopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK uses fopen for REST API queries (also for Blob requests). Because REST APIs have a URI Scheme, you need allow_url_fopen to be turned ON.

What kind of alternative are you looking for? The only alternative I see, is to modify the SDK code to avoid the usage of fopen. Maybe with cUrl? But I would not recommend it either...